# vertical drop down menu getting cut off in IE using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

The drop down box as well as the longest option in drop down gets cut off in IE7. This works fine in Mozilla and chrome. I am new to JSP and javascript.

I am using:

`style="width:240%"`

Option for the drop down is fetched from db. Even if the option is visible it goes out of the page and hence looks odd.

Is there a way to display the option in 2 lines in JSP?

please help

Answer (score 1):

try `style = auto`, that means it automatically goes to the width of the longest option.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option to, remove the width from the style, this usually causes issues with select lists in IE. If not, multi line select list options aren't possible with html select list controls, but you can use a div that can act as a dropdown list using JavaScript and css. http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/page/jquerycombobox.aspx